# Facebook FQL: Can we pass custom width / height to query the photo_src?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql, photo

I am trying to query photo from facebook using Graph API Explorer but not working

This is what put in.

```
SELECT src From photo_src where photo_id IN (SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE owner = me())
```

I received no data... But my account does have photos.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, not all photo's have a photo_src connection to their disposal. I would just use src_big, src_small or src in the photo table.

Comment: but src_big and src_small can be blank though

Comment: Damn Facebook FQL, feels like one big black magic box.